# Ordering rows which has specific data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have following query :

```
select mau_sav_scheme.scheme_id, mau_sav_scheme.scheme_name, mau_sav_scheme.sav_type from mau_sav_scheme
         inner join sav_acc_mcg
         on mau_sav_scheme.scheme_id = sav_acc_mcg.scheme_id
         GROUP BY mau_sav_scheme.scheme_id, mau_sav_scheme.scheme_name, mau_sav_scheme.sav_type 
order by sav_type,scheme_id
```

Result is :

```
 scheme_id   scheme_name              sav_type 
    005       gghhj                     1
    019       asdf                      2
    001       shf{ ;'/If)f sf]if        3
    002       ;d'x art                  3
    003       ;d'x s                    3
    004       ;d'x v                    3
```

I want to order the row in such a way that, the top row is always the row containing 'sav_type'=2. 'sav_type' datatype is nvarchar.
I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply order by a `CASE` statement as a first criteria;

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN sav_type='2' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, sav_type, scheme_id
```

That will put all rows with sav_type=2 first in your sort order, followed by all other rows sorted by the other two existing criteria.